# Drop down menu hover state

Tags: html, css, button, drop-down-menu, hover

I'm working on a drop down menu and have run in to a spot of bother getting the hover effect to work the way I intended. When I hover over an image I want the drop down action to take place, this is working fine. But I also want the text below the image to act like a tab connecting the text and the drop down menu.

I have put together this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acott/y2BtT/) example to give a rough idea.So when I hover over the button the background of the 'HOVER' text should turn green. but it only turns green when I hover directly over the text, I would like it to run the hover effect when I hover over the actual button. I hope this makes sense?

heres the html :

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><div class="btn"><p>HOVER</p></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
.btn{
    display: block;
    width: 68px;
    height: 22px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding-right:30px;
    text-align:center;
}

.btn{
    background: url("http://www.aidancotter.com/images/face.png") no-repeat -5px 0px;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-position: -5px -120px;
}

.menu ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

.menu{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding:20px 0 0 20px;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}

.btn p{
    font-family:Arial;
    padding:10px;
    color:#000;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.btn p:hover{
    background:#78a802;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#fff;
}

.menu ul li ul{
    display:none;
    background:#78a802;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:95px;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
    line-height:30px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: *when I hover over the button the background of the 'HOVER' text should turn green.* <- Please explain a little better?

Comment: Sorry, the background of the text below the image should turn the same colour as the drop down, if you have a look at the jsfiddle example and place your mouse over the text below the button the background will turn green but I would like this to happen when you place your cursor over the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

```
li:hover div{  background-position: -5px -120px; color:green}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y2BtT/15/)**

---

For text BG color, you need to add another tag around the text

```
li:hover span{  background-color:#78a802; color:green; display:block} 
li:hover div{  background-position: -5px -120px; color:green}
```

**[DEMO 2 UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/y2BtT/25/)**

Comment: Thanks for this, instead of the text turning green I would like the background of the text to turn green

Comment: I think that your solution is the way to go but he wants a "tab connection" which I think would result in changing your rule into something like that: li:hover div{  background-position: -5px -120px; background-color:#78a802}

Comment: Perfect, and it keeps the hover state once the user moves into the drop down! Lovely, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property in CSS:

```
.btn:hover p {
    background-color: #78a802;
}
```

Updated [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/y2BtT/20/).

Comment: That did the trick, excellent! is there a way to keep the hover state active once the user has moved the mouse into the drop down menu?

Comment: @acott You can use `li` instead of `.btn`.